# sufficient statistic for uniform

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics

Given that $\theta$ is an integer and that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables which are Uniformly distributed on the integers $1, 2, \ldots, \theta$, prove that $X_1 + X_2$ is not sufficient for $\theta$.

I'm pretty new on the topic of sufficiency and not sure how to argue reasonably. We could start from showing $P(X =x \mid T = t)$ (where $X$ is vector of $X$s and $T$ is sufficient statistic) does not depend on theta, but sure if this is the best way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_1+X_2=5.$ One might think that means
$$
(X_1,X_2) =(1,4) \text{ or } (X_1,X_2)=(2,3) \text{ or } (X_1,X_2) = (3,2) \text{ or } (X_1,X_2) = (4,1). 
$$
And if $\theta\ge4,$ then that is correct. But what if $\theta=3$? Then you'd have
$$
(X_1,X_2) = (2,3) \text{ or } (X_1,X_2) = (3,2).
$$
Thus the conditional distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ given $X_1+X_2$ depends on $\theta.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So we generally use counter examples to show insufficiency. Say for $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are 3 bernoulli (p) distribution. How would you show T = $X_1 X_2 + X_3$ was not sufficient (does not depend on p) with a counter example.

Comment: @bstead : I'd start by looking at what happens with small values of $\theta. \qquad$